# How to convert a dict object in requests.models.Response object in Python?

Tags: python, json, patch

I am trying to test a function which contain an API call. So in the function I have this line of code :

```
api_request = dict(requests.get(url_of_the_API).json())
```

So I tried to use patch like this :

```
@patch('requests.get')
def test_products_list_creator(self, mock_get):
                
    mock_get.return_value = json.dumps({"products":
        {
            "name": "apple",
            "categories": "fruit,red"
        }
    })
```

But at the line of my API call, python throw me this error :

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I tried to print `type(requests.get(url_of_the_API}.json"))` to know what it was and I got this : `<class 'requests.models.Response'>`

There is a lot of questions about convert a Response in dict but didn't found any about converting a dict to a Response.

So how to make my patch callable by the method json() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly we need to figure what is required by `requests.models.Response`'s method `.json` in order to work, this can be done by scrying source code available at github - [`requests.models` source](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/models.py). After reading `requests.models.Response.json` body we might conclude that if `encoding` is set, it does simply loads `.text`. `text` method has `@property` decorator, meaning it is computed when accessing `.text`, this in turn depend on `.content` which also is computed. After scrying `.content` it should be clear that if we set `._content` value then it will be returned by `.content`, therefore to make fake Response which do support `.json` we need to create one and set `.encoding` and `._content` of it, consider following example:

```
from requests.models import Response
resp = Response()
resp.encoding = 'ascii'
resp._content = b'{"x":100}'
print(resp.json())
```

output

```
{'x': 100}
```

Note that `_content` value needs to be `bytes` so if you have dict `d` then to get value to be put there do `json.dumps(d).encode('ascii')`